# Parse a jquery .map() like array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a Fiddle that shows how I get an jq .map() array of the status of the checkboxes on my site. It produces the following object in the console:

```
 [Object {name="Sunday", status="Checked"}, Object {name="Monday", status="Checked"}, Object     {name="Tuesday", status="UnChecked"}]
```

The object is saved to local storage. Now, obviously, on next time the user visits the page, I want to pull that object back and parse it to check off the previously checked boxes (yes, I am aware local storage is not ideal, but it is fine for this project). I know how to programmatic check off the checkboxes, but I cannot seem to loop through the saved object.

Here is the code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alsosun/ab316mkr/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web storage only support string values. Thus, you need to convert your object to a JSON string using `JSON.stringify(obj)` before saving it.

When you retrieve it, you can parse it back to an object, using either `JSON.parse(str)` or `$.parseJSON(str)`.

Updated fiddle with example: http://jsfiddle.net/ab316mkr/5/

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage):

> Note: Keep in mind that everything you store in any of the storages described in this page is converted to string using its .toString method before being stored. So trying to store a common object will result in string "[object Object]" to be stored instead of the object or its JSON representation. Using native JSON parsing and serialization methods provided by the browser is a good and common way for storing objects in string format.

Comment: Ahh, that is why my attempts to parse failed. Great!